# リスト型内にある辞書を全て出力した結果が欲しい

Tags: python, python3

## 環境 - Python3.8

#### 元コード(経緯について)

Slackのbotでpayloadを作成して投稿する部分を作成しています。

```py
# カラーコード
color_dict = {
    0:"#adffad",1:"#adffff",
    2:"#ffffad",3:"#d6adff",
    4:"#ffd6ad",5:"#bfc0c1"
}
# パターン
pattern1 = ['A','B','C','','E','']
pattern2 = ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE','FF']

# パターン分の箱
value,n1 = [''] * len(pattern1),[''] * len(pattern1)
text,n2 = [''] * len(pattern2),[''] * len(pattern2)

field = [{'title': n1[i], 'value': value[i]} for i in range(len(pattern1)) if value[i] != ""]
color = "" if not field else "#f56c6c"

data = [{'title': n2[i], 'text': text[i], 'color': color_dict.get(i)} for i in range(len(pattern2))]


print (data)
[
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#adffad'},
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#adffff'}, 
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#ffffad'}, 
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#d6adff'}, 
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#ffd6ad'}, 
    {'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': '#bfc0c1'}
]
# 見やすいように整形しています。


payload = {
    "attachments": [{
            "fields" : field,
            "color" : color,
        },
        # 出力はされるがこんな感じでは書きたくない・・・・。
        data[0],data[1],
        data[2],data[3],
        data[4],data[5]
    ],
}
print (payload)
```

dataの部分を上手いことできないか？ というところで、タイトルにもあるように辞書を全て出力する方法を知りたいというものです。

### dict型で以下のような結果が欲しい。

```py
print (ex)
{"title":"","text":"","color":""},
{"title":"","text":"","color":""},
{"title":"","text":"","color":""},
{"title":"","text":"","color":""}
```

### 試したこと① 最後の結果しか表示されない。

```py
ex = {}
for x in data:
    ex |= x
print (ex)
{'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': ''}

print (type(ex))
<class 'dict'>
```

### 試したこと② str型に変わってしまう。

```py
s = ",".join(map(str,data))

print (s)
{'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': ''},
{'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': ''},
{'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': ''},
{'title': '', 'text': '', 'color': ''}

print (type(s))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。更新させていただきました。
誤：
data = [
    {"a","A"},
    {"b","B"},
    {"c","C"},
    {"d","D"}
    ]
正:
data = [
    {"a":"A"},
    {"b":"B"},
    {"c":"C"},
    {"d":"D"}
    ]

Comment: 欲しい結果は**試したこと②**の`print(x)`を`print(ex)`に書き換えた場合の出力結果`{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C', 'd': 'D'}`(辞書を連結)ではありませんか？そうではなくあくまでもリストから辞書型4つを個別に取り出して連結せず、リスト型でもstr型でもなく、4つの辞書型を順番にコンソールへ出力したいのでしょうか？

Comment: 元の `data` は(現在) `dict`型の `list`のようですが, 試したこと② ③ を見ると, `set`型のようですが, `set`型ですか？ … 矛盾があってどちらの型の listなのかが不明です

Comment: @payaneco さん、@oriri さん コメントありがとうございます。 
そもそも、元のデータを簡略化して書いたのが誤っていました。 使用しているデータを書き換えて、再修正と再検証しました。 よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 今度は欲しい結果が分かりません。辞書を合成するでもなく一つにまとめる構造はありません(それこそ listしか)

Comment: @oriri
>print(x)をprint(ex)に書き換えた場合の出力結果。
何度も修正申し訳ありません。簡略化して書いたものがそもそも誤ったDataでしたので、素のデータを書き換えて再度修正しました。
これだと確認したところ、やはり最後のデータのみ出力されます。

>4つの辞書型を順番にコンソールへ出力したいのでしょうか？
いえ、変数内にまとめて格納したいと思っています。
printはあくまで確認用で、変数内の内容が欲しい結果の内容になってればOKという認識です。

Comment: `{'k1':'v1'}, {'k2': 'v2'},...` … このような構造(カンマで連結する構造)は Pythonに無いので持つことができません。listとして持つことはできますが, それだと `data` と同じです (あるいは tupleですが, 編集できない listのようなもので, あまり変わりません)

Comment: star operator を使って、`payload = {"attachments": [{"fields": "TEST", "color": "#adffad"}, *data]}` とすれば良いかと。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict` を ',' で連結するデータ構造はありませんが
データ構造の中に組み込むことは可能です

```py
payload = {
    "attachments": [{
            "fields" : "TEST",
            "color" : "#adffad",
        },
        *data
    ],
}
print(payload)
```

---

参考
[https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=アンパック](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)

Comment: おぉ！そんなやり方があるんですね。
無事解決しました。ありがとうごございますorz

Answer (score 0):

以下の方法で解決しました。ご回答ありがとうございました。

```py
# カラーコード
color_dict = {
    0:"#adffad",1:"#adffff",
    2:"#ffffad",3:"#d6adff",
    4:"#ffd6ad",5:"#bfc0c1"
}
# パターン
pattern1 = ['A','B','C','','E','']
pattern2 = ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE','FF']

# パターン分の箱
value,n1 = [''] * len(pattern1),[''] * len(pattern1)
text,n2 = [''] * len(pattern2),[''] * len(pattern2)

field = [{'title': n1[i], 'value': value[i]} for i in range(len(pattern1)) if value[i] != ""]
color = "" if not field else "#f56c6c"

data = [{'title': n2[i], 'text': text[i], 'color': color_dict.get(i)} for i in range(len(pattern2))]

payload = {
    "attachments": [{
            "fields" : field,
            "color" : color,
        },
        *data
    ],
}
print (payload)
```